# Oracle UCP dynamic mbean objectName

Tags: oracle, dynamic, jmx, ucp, objectname

I am trying to use the restful interface to invoke the Mbeans, can someone shed light as to how to connect to a dynamic ObjectName like that of the UCP.

Eg:

oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolMBean:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManager-235353075192192801-2-vx20fb

How do I make a connection to this objectName with some randum number and hostname at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I just had to make use of wildcard.

```
Set<ObjectName> nameSet = myMBeanServer.queryNames(new ObjectName(
       "oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolMBean:name=UniversalConnectionPoolManager*"), null);
```

This is solved.